# How do I get my code to stop having Segmentation Faults?

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, arm64, armv8

I'm trying to get this assembly code to print out an array of random numbers and then use an insertion sort algorithim to print out a sorted list. However, my code will only print out the unsorted list and then stop at a segmentation fault.

```
fmt1: .string "v[%d] = %d\n"
fmt2: .string "\nSorted array:\n"
fmt3: .string "v[%d] = %d\n"

.balign 4
.global main

alloc = -(16+20+16+16) & -16
dealloc = -alloc

define(i, w9)
define(v, x10)
define(c, x9)
define(j, w18)
define(temp, w19)
define(temp64, x19)
define(offset, x11)
define(fp, x29)
define(lr, x30)

main:
    stp fp, lr, [sp, alloc]!
    mov fp, sp

    mov x8, #0
    bl srand

    mov i, 2
    str i, [fp, 36]

    add sp, sp, -8 & -16
    str wzr, [fp, -8]
    b test1

loop1:
    bl rand
    and x0, x0, #255

    str x0, [fp, -20]

    add v, fp, 16
    ldr w11, [fp, -8]
    ldr c, [fp, -20]
    lsl offset, offset, 3
    add v, v, offset
    str c, [v]

    ldr i, [fp, -8]
    add i, i, 1
    str i, [fp, -8]
test1:
    ldr i, [fp, -8]
    cmp i, 50
    b.lt loop1

    add sp, sp, 16

    str wzr, [fp, 40]
    b test2

loop2:
    ldr x0, =fmt1
    ldr w1, [fp, 40]
    add c, fp, 16
    ldr x2, [c, w1, SXTW 3]
    bl printf

    ldr i, [fp, 40]
    add i, i, 1
    str i, [fp, 40]
test2:
    ldr i, [fp, 40]
    cmp i, 50
    b.lt loop2

    mov i, #1
sort_outer_1:
    cmp i, #50
    b.gt print

    ldr temp64, [v, i, SXTW 3]
sort_inner:
    mov j, i
    cmp j, #0
    ble sort_outer_2

    ldr c, [v, j, SXTW 3]
    sxtw temp64, temp
    cmp temp64, c
    b.ge sort_outer_2

    ldr c, [v, j, SXTW 3]
    str c, [v, j, SXTW 3]

    subs j, j, #1
    b sort_inner

sort_outer_2:
    str temp64, [v, j, SXTW 3]
    add i, i, 1
    b sort_outer_1

print:
    ldr x0, =fmt2
    bl printf

    ldr x0, =fmt3
    bl printf

end:
    ldp fp, lr, [sp], dealloc
    ret
```

Since It was a segfault I assumed that the negative offsets were the problem since it might've been reading info from outside the stack, but putting in positve offsets gave me the same error. Then I assumed the first use of the stack was wasting 20 bytes of space, so I changed from 36 to 16. I also used gdb, and it seems this line: ( ldr c, [v, j, SXTW 3]) is the cause.  Can anyone help me see whats wrong?

Comment: Segfault on which instruction, with what register values?  Your debugger should tell you: when execution stops at the segfault, `disas` to disassemble (or `layout asm` or `layout reg`), and `info reg` or `p /x $x30` or whatever.

Comment: Array reference out of bounds, null pointer dereference, stack mishandling leading to the prior or bad return address, are the main causes.  Really, how to stop these is by having a correct algorithm and correct implementation.  Do you have a working & correct C implementation?  That can help by being something to compare with srep by step.

Comment: Yes, but the memory managment has to be done manually. I have no clue what's wrong here though.

Comment: What values are in `v` (your alias for x10) and `j` (your alias for w18) when it faults?  See my first comment for how to get GDB to show you the register values.  `x10 + (j<<3)` is a bad pointer.  Perhaps your loop didn't exit when you intended so you kept incrementing until a bad page.  Or decrementing since `j` is decreasing?  Or no, it gets overwritten with `i` every time in the inner loop?  That seems weird.  Also, why is there a `str c, [v, j, SXTW 3]` right after a load into into the same register from the same addressing-mode?  That has no effect.